# problem in management error in service angular 11

Tags: angular

**Hi, I want to fix the errors and get an error in the appComponent when an error occurs. But first enter res and then enter Error. How can I solve this problem?**

I want when I encounter an error, do not enter Res in the component anymore and enter the error directly

**appService:**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  constructor(private http:HttpClient){}
  run() {
    console.log('app service')
  }
  postData(data:string):Observable<any>{
    return this.http.post('',data)
    .pipe(
      map((data:any)=>{
        return this.success(data);
      }),
      catchError(error=>{
        this.error(error);
        return throwError('error');
      })
    )
  }
  success(data){
      // Other commands
    // ... 
    // ...
    return data;
  }
  error(error){
    // Other commands
    // ... 
    // ...
    return error;

  }
}
```

**appComponent:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular 4';
  constructor(private service:AppService){
     this.sendDate()
  }
  sendDate(){
    this.service.postData('test').subscribe(
      res=>{
        console.log("OK")
      },
      error=>{
        console.log("--NOK--")
      }
    )
  }
}
```

**console:**

```
OK
OK
post http://url 500(internal server error)
OK
OK
--NOK--
```

Comment: Please don't use google translator. Nobody's gonna troll you for your grammar mistakes. But google translator is horrific.

Comment: @alio you can add `catchError` to app.component.ts too! it will reject other stream if error occures.

Comment: can I manegmant error?

Comment: @alito try to use catchError inside app.component. too, and see when error occurs what happen next.

Comment: I ask the server and it gives an error, how can I prevent the res from entering the component?
Please give an example

Comment: @alito `this.service.postData('test').pipe(catchError (error => error)). subscribe()` do this in component.ts file

Comment: No, this method does not work, it still enters the component and prints the OK message when I encounter an error